# Pine-Script: Plot horizontal line on specific stock and price

Tags: pine-script, stock

I am trying to plot a horizontal line on a specific stock and price.

I tried this, but it is getting plotted on all the stocks (whichever I choose). It should be only in APPLE stock.

```
//@version=4
study("Example", overlay=true)
symbol = "AAPL"
price = 154
apple = security(symbol, "D", price)
plot(apple)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `syminfo.ticker` built-in variable to check if you are on APPL.

```
is_aapl = (syminfo.ticker == "AAPL")

plot(is_aapl ? apple : na)
```

Comment: Not able to replicate. Getting different errors. Tries many examples. It always comes to some different errors. I am not pine script expert. Can you please share another way or share more details? Please